# Windows installer windows are automatically moved topleftwards and out of the screen after installation has been completed

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer

[image]

See this screenshot for a better description. Brand New Windows 10 20H2 installed today using Win10_20H2_v2_English_x64.iso with these commands:

```
diskpart
select disk 0
clean
create partition primary
format fs=ntfs
assign letter=C
active
quit
dism /apply-image /imagefile:E:\sources\install.wim /index:7 /applydir C:\
bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f ALL
```

The file is PowerShell-7.2.0-preview.2-win-x64.msi, the window can't be dragged, is there a way to fix this(I mean to prevent the windows from being moved out of screen)? Any help would be appreciated.

OKay, the current monitor is Huntkey N2271WH M2150002, screen resolution is 1920x1080, display resolution is 1920x1080, got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't install the latest drivers optimal for your graphics card, you said you did a clean install, the drivers Windows installs are generic drivers for best compatibility, not specifically tailored for your graphics card. So this problem might happen.

I once faced a similar problem, I solved this by installing optimal drivers using Snappy Driver Installer. It is open source; You can use this or a similar software. Then it should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed more MSI files before and accidentaly somehow moved this window to the edge of the screen and then this window remebers its old position and goes back there. So firmly drag it to a suitable place, interact with it and normally close.

Also, This little problem can happen for a couple of different reasons. The most common is if you have a secondary monitor that is sometimes hooked up and sometimes not—something that's pretty common for laptop users. Sometimes, if you disconnect the secondary monitor without turning off the "extend desktop" setting in Windows or moving your windows back to your main monitor first, windows that were on the second monitor can get stranded. This can even happen with the new, more multi-monitor-friendly settings in Windows. This window problem can also happen sometimes if an app moves a window off screen and doesn't move it back.

There are some few more ways too:

[image]

Here you can use "Cascade windows", "Show windows stacked" or "Show windows side by side". To get this menu just right click on an empty space on taskbar.

- The Cascade windows option will arrange your open windows in a "cascade" allowing you to see all their title bars at once.
- The Show windows stacked, it allows you to arrange your windows stacked vertically on top of each other.
- The Show windows side by side, it allows you to have Windows automatically arrange your open windows side-by-side with each other.

So your windows get out of the corners, and you get rid of the problem.

Comment: No, I have not installed it, I did say it's CLEAN install and I didn't move it there...

Comment: The window can't be dragged normally, I had found a way to drag it: LB RB Move Arrow keys...